# Can any find wso2 esb with jboss mq

Tags: jboss, wso2, esb

Can anyone help with wso2 esb with jboss mq.
Need a example for using JBoss MQ to store message from esb jms store.

Answer (score 0):

Would this help: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Configure+with+JBossMQ ? You can then use generic JMS samples once you've setup JBoss MQ.

A sample with JBoss Messaging: https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=50500327